# What is the format of these data files? CNT, LAB, PAL, etc

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, feature-class, data-management, feature-dataset

I was given data which is arranged in folders as shown in the following picture:
[image: In the attached picture: 2885/09 folder means the data is of grid-index 2885-09 as defined in Modified UTM projection defined for Nepal. BUILD_PT, ...HYDRO_AR etc are shown as Feature Datasets in ArcCatalog. And each feature datasets]

[image: The folder structure in ArcCatalog]

I am using ArcGIS 10.1. I believe feature datasets in ArcGIS only exist in geodatabases. But the datasets are arranged in folders. Can someone tell me the name of the format of the data? I want to use arcpy to merge datasets from every grid-sheet. I can merge .shp, .dbf files. But I do not know how to merge for example 2885/09/HYDRO_AR with 2885/10/HYDRO_AR in the given datasets. Because HYDRO_AR contains many files.

Comment: It's an ArcInfo Coverage - see [What is the difference between Coverage, Shapefiles and Geodatabases in ArcGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113894/what-is-the-difference-between-coverage-shapefiles-and-geodatabases-in-arcgis) and [What is a coverage - ArcGIS Desktop Help 9.3](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=what_is_a_coverage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an ArcInfo Coverage - see What is the difference between Coverage, Shapefiles and Geodatabases in ArcGIS? and What is a coverage - ArcGIS Desktop Help 9.3

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% sure, but it looks very much like an old-style Arc/Info Coverage. I clearly remember those having TIC, AAT and BND files.

This format is somewhat similar to a file geodatabase, in that they both consist of a folder containing a number of files that make up one or more featureclasses. Their actual (binary) format is entirely different though.

Here is a link to the Esri documentation: http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=what_is_a_coverage

Comment: More specifically, it is a workspace of pre-7.0 coverages. https://www.google.com/search?site=&q=arcinfo+7.0+workspace&oq=arcinfo+7.0+workspace

Comment: @Vince I don't remember ever seeing a *.dbf in a coverage but everything else looks like a coverage to me.  Have some *.adf files been renamed or I have I forgotten?

Comment: Doh! Screen too small - The .dbf coverages were **PC** ArcInfo 3.x/4.0 (circa 1990)