# ArcGIS Python TableSelect_analysis ERROR 000210: Cannot create output

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, table, select, error-000210

I have a very strange issue:
I try to execute the following script which uses TableSelect_analysis and construct as outputs the corresponding tables from another table depending on a specific attribute. For example I have 1000 rows with urban, rural and industrial areas and I want to output 3 files each with the corresponding kind of area.

The code:

```
for idx, description in enumerate(greeklishDescrList):  
    description = description.replace(" ", "_")  
    outSHP = outDir + description + u".shp"  
    idxOriginal = descrList[idx]  
    arcpy.TableSelect_analysis(r"C:\r*******d\R********l.gdb\l*********I.shp", outSHP, "\"descr\" = '" + idxOriginal + "'")
```

What happens is this:

In the first iteration of the for loop it does select all the rows with the correct value "descr".

1st ISSUE:

Output name in the gdb is "shp" when it should have named it as I have coded elsewhere as RURAL.shp . In the contents of "shp" table everything is as expected.

2nd ISSUE:

In the next iteration it breaks down showing the following message:

> ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output
>   C:\r*********d\R********l.gdb\URBAN.shp Failed to execute
>   (TableSelect).

Through the Python scripting environment of ArcGIS (I code through PyCharm) it also shows the following

[image: screenshotResults]

Troubleshooting:

1. The path is correct. It is clear also from the fact that it constructes the problematic "shp.shp" table with -however- the correct values.
2. There are permissions available for the same reason as (1)
3. I have excluded the gdb and the whole directory from my Microsoft Security Essentials
4. The files do not exist (I believe!). I delete them from the gdb through ArcGIS and I restarted everything multiple times

ArcGIS 10.3.1 with Python 2.7.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to specify shapefiles within a geodatabase and this was causing all of the malfuctions. I have constructed a different folder and assigned the ouputs there and everything is in fine order.

For details and deeper input from @Vince:

> You cannot place shapefiles in a file geodatabase. They are different
>   formats. You can convert a shapefile to an FGDB table, but then it is
>   no longer a shapefile -- it is now a table. FGDB tables cannot have a
>   ".shp" suffix, because they cannot have any suffix -- The "."
>   character is not permitted in table names. The files within the .gdb
>   directory can only by managed by the FGDB. Placing other files there
>   makes them invisible to ArcGIS.

and from @ed.hank:

> [What is the difference between Coverage, Shapefiles and Geodatabases in ArcGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113894/what-is-the-difference-between-coverage-shapefiles-and-geodatabases-in-arcgis)